# What other languages have a similar concept to Chapel's config variables

Tags: command-line, chapel

I just discovered Chapel's config variable modifier which is great for command line operations. Are there other languages or frameworks that mimic this feature so I don't have to program the filters each time?

Answer (score 2):

### The width of all different [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) `config`-s is indeed unparalleled:

```
config var   VAR  = 1;         //  --VAR=10         sets other value from cmdline
                               //  --VAR 20         sets other value too
config const RHO  = 1.23456;   //  --RHO=0.123456   sets other value from cmdline
                               //  --RHO 0.2468     sets other value too
                               //  --RHO=0.39*VAR   sets other value for COMPILER
                               //                                    based on VAR
config param DBG  = false;     // -s DBG=true       sets other value from cmdline
config type  B    = uint(8);   //    -sB='uint(16)' sets other value from cmdline
                               //    -sB='if DBG then uint(32) else uint(16)'
                               //                   sets other value for COMPILER
                               //                                    based on DBG
```

While there is yet a must to have a compile-time known typing, which is a certain restriction ( for strong-typed, compiled languages both obvious and natural ), still the flexibility of use of these constructs for ad-hoc setup of an adaptive run-time configurable behaviour is great and hard to parallel in other language / compiler environments.